# How to delete first X entries in the List<Double>

Tags: java, list, arraylist

How to implement the following operation?

Let's say there is a list:

```
List<Double> allStops = getAllStops();
```

Also, there is another list:

```
List<Double> implementedStops = getImplementedStops();
```

What is the correct way to delete fist X entries of the list `allStops`, where X is the size of `implementedStops`?

For instance, if the list `allStops` contains the following entries:

```
[0] = 21
[1] = 25
[2] = 30
[3] = 15
```

.., and the size of `implementedStops` is 2, then the result should be the following:

```
[0] = 30
[1] = 15
```

Comment: By "delete", do you want the remaining entries to shift down, or do you want the deleted entries to be nulled out?

Comment: I want to receive a new List<Double> without first X entries, so that the remaining entries are shifted up. In my example, the result should be: [0] = 30; [1] = 15

Comment: Shouldn't this be as simple as calling `remove(0)` as many times as entries you need removed?

Comment: replying to your last clarification, do you need the original list to be modified or do you need a new list to be created?

Comment: I need a new list to be created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        int count = 2;
        List<Double> lst = new ArrayList<>();
        lst.add(1.3);
        lst.add(14.2);
        lst.add(15.6);
        System.out.println(lst);

        List<Double> newlst = count<lst.size()?lst.subList(count, lst.size()):new ArrayList<Double>();
        System.out.println(newlst);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use subList()-method:

```
List<Double> result = allStops.subList(implementedStops.size(), allStops.size());
```

Comment: What happens if implementedStops.size() > allStops.size()?

Comment: Wouldn't that be logically impossible?

Answer (score 0):

"Removes from this list all of the elements whose index is between fromIndex, inclusive, and toIndex, exclusive."

```
strings.removeRange(0, 2);
```

Comment: I guess that there should be strings.remove(0) instead of strings.remove(i); Isn't it?

Comment: No because then it only removes the first element

Comment: When the first element is removed, the second element is the new first element...

Comment: Just curious, where did you find this `removeRange()`method?

Comment: @user3774329 Hmmm, never knew that existed, probably because that's an implementation detail for `ArrayList` and not part of the `List` interface proper. It's `protected`, though, so the chances of you actually being able to use it is practically nil...